# Azure data gateway account permissions

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-logic-apps

When installing an azure data gateway, the installer requires an email address of an organizational account, which it then signs into azure with.

For testing, i have been using my own account, but for a live system, should a dedicated "service" account be created for the data gateway?

Comment: What will happen when you quit this job? This is just one of the reasons not to use personal accounts for infrastructure deployments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> During gateway installation, you sign in with your Azure account, which links your gateway installation to your Azure account and only that account. Later, in the Azure portal, you must use the same Azure account and Azure AD tenant when you create an Azure gateway resource that registers and claims your gateway installation. In Azure Logic Apps, on-premises triggers and actions then use the gateway resource for connecting to on-premises data sources.

You **need to sign in with either a work account or school account**, also known as an organization account, which looks like username@contoso.com. **You can't use Azure B2B (guest) accounts or personal Microsoft accounts**, such as @hotmail.com or @outlook.com.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install).